# How to create a bot in my website that checks if the user is really online or offline and update his status in the database

Tags: php, jquery

U want the bot ro check every 30 seconds to every single user if they are really online and offline by sending a request and if the bot dont get any respond after 20 sexonds they will update the status on the satabase ro offline. 
Like 
  $con->query("UPDATE users SET status='offline' WHERE username='$username');
I want the bot to check on all users online. Offline users dont need to be checked. It doesnt need to ne a super modded bot. I just need the simplest form of a bot that can perform the following actions.

Comment: post your attempted code so far.

Comment: As of now. I hae no idead how. I actually asked on how to do that. But all i know is to update. But i dont know how to send the request and stuff. I hope u undershand. Im still a begginer i hope nobody down votes it.

Comment: I think 30 sec is to less to detect the activity ? from my point of view it should be in minutes ( may be 3 or 5).

Comment: Its ok if it would take minutes. Its dine. I just need a bot that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send anything to the client without prior receiving a request from it. Thats why its called a client, and the server is called a server, cos he serves. 
If we could send data to the browsers without browsers 1st asking us for it, it would lead to a really huge security problem.

**Solution**

You must implement this in both, the javascript and php, but it is not a simple task.

One solution would be to listen for a user's [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/#fn) with jquery javascript, and than when the user is not moving his mouse for X seconds, you send a http request to the server telling him that the user is AFK.

Comment: Wow thats a great explanation there. But how? Can u edit ad add lines of codes that detect the mouse moves???